# Как организовать включения файлов?

Tags: include, c++

Здравствуйте.
Есть файл "project.h", который включает все нужные .h:

```
#include "driver.h"
#include "animation.h"
#include "eventRec.h"
// etc

#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

А также файлы "a.h" и "b.h" с одноименным классами внутри. Класс A включает объект класса B. Нужно подключить "a.h" и "b.h" с помощью "project.h" (чтобы у обоих был доступ к driver и пр.)

A.h:

```
#include "project.h"

class A 
{
private:
    B obj;
};
```

B.h:

```
#include "project.h"

class B
{
private:
    //something
};
```

При таком раскладе не компилируется - понятно - бесконечный цикл включения.
Пробовал ставить include guardы в каждом файле:

```
#ifndef name_h
#define name_h

/* Тело класса */

#endif
```

При таком раскладе A не видит B.

```
error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "obj"
error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
```

Помогите достичь цели.

Comment: Чтобы `A` видел `B`, в `a.h` надо явно прописать 

    #include "b.h"

до 

    class A {
      private:
        B obj;
    };

(надеюсь, что `B` у Вас явно (не по указателю) не ссылается на `A` :)).

Что же касается ошибки с отсутствием `;` и `int`, то, не видя всего кода, сказать что-то определенное не могу.

Comment: Это весь код. В main`е подключается "project.h" и всё. Под "не видит" я и подразумевал эту ошибку.

Comment: @sloow_ua, ну, тогда вместо

         //something

в `B` надо написать что-то более осмысленное.

Comment: @avp: Упс, проглядел этот момент. Сейчас у меня там "int a" и конструктор в паблике. Но в целом - ошибка заключается в том, что компилятор не может найти нужный класс (B).

Comment: @sloow_ua, т.е. Вы написали все guards, добавили в `a.h` `#include "b.h"`, и все равно та же ошибка?

Тогда попробуйте все же сначала аккуратно записать весь текст ("заинклюдить вручную") в одном файле, а уже потом разбить его на несколько `.h`.

Comment: @avp: Нет, если подключить напрямую b.h к a.h, то всё ок. Пытался реализовать с одним файлом проекта - хочется разобраться, почему не работает так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала: include guard'ы необходимы, без вопросов.

Затем: ошибка состоит в том, что вы пытаетесь облегчить себе жизнь, сделав «универсальный» `header` и пытаясь подключить его везде. Так не пойдёт. Включайте только то, что нужно, и только там, где нужно. Например:

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED

#include "b.h"

class A 
{
private:
    B obj;
};

#endif
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "project.h"

...
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H_INCLUDED
#define B_H_INCLUDED

class B
{
private:
    //
};

#endif
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "project.h"

...
```

Comment: Почему не работает таким образом? Должно вроде бы. Выходит примерно такой порядок включения, если забыть про driver и пр.:
main -> project -> a -> project -> b -> project -> end. И в таком случае всё должно работать. 
Или я не прав?

Ну и интересно, как это реализовано в сторонних библиотеках/игровых движках. В SDL либо Cocos`е один .h файл, который уже включает все остальные.

Comment: @sloow_ua: Ну, смотрите сами. Без include guard'ов понятно, что бесконечный цикл. С include guard'ами, компилируем A.cpp:

1. A.cpp начинается, включает project.h
2. project.h начинается, определяет `PROJECT_H_INCLUDED`
3. project.h включает A.h
4. A.h определяет `A_H_INCLUDED` и снова включает project.h
5. project.h **не** отрабатывает, т. к. определён `PROJECT_H_INCLUDED`
6. Продолжается компиляция A.h, не видит `B`
_____
@sloow_ua: А в Cocos'е, небось, вместо #include используется #import.

Comment: @VladD: Если в "project.h" без include guard`ов:
1. Project.h
2. Включает A.h; определяет A_H
3. A.h включает Project.h
4. Project.h включает A.h, но определен A_H, класс не переопределяется (сразу вопрос: если сам файл включается дважды, но внутри не отрабатывает из-за определенного #define, это ок?)
5. Project.h включает B.h; определяет B_H
6. B.h включает Project.h
7. Пункт 4.
8. Тоже самое, но с B.h

B.h включен в A.h.

Comment: @sloow_ua: А ошибка та же?

Comment: @VladD Да, такая же, как и в вопросе. Я в project`е guard`ы не ставил.

Comment: @sloow_ua: Не должно быть. У меня в коде была ошибка — два раза `#ifndef` вместо одного `#define`, может, вы её скопипастили? Если исправить, всё работает как и ожидалось.

Тем не менее, полагаться на порядок `#include`'ов и тому подобные штуки не принято и скорее всего ведёт к неприятным ошибкам. Делайте правильно.

Comment: @VladD: Проверил еще раз - работает. Вероятно, где-то в тот раз накосячил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще один вариант - вообще не включать ничего в файл-хедер и сделать предопределение класса:

```
class B;

class A 
{
private:
    B obj;
};
```

А уже в cpp, где все будет реализовываться, подключить B. Это избавит вас от проблем с дублирующимися определениями, поскольку cpp, по идее, никуда подключаться не должен (по идее, т.к. как минимум теоретически это возможно). Но гарды все равно нужны.

Comment: @aknew: Это не откомпилируется: компилятору нужно знать, сколько памяти занимает экземпляр `B`, так что одной только forward-декларации недостаточно. Сработало бы, если бы вместо `B obj` было бы `B* pObj`.